# VIM function for creating new a file with a header including the filename and a timestamp

Tags: vim, vimrc

I have created a VIM function that generates a new file based on the arguments passed to it and on some zsh variables I have setup.

Is it possible to extend this function to insert a header into this file immediately as it is created? I'm trying to insert the name of the file on line 1, a time stamp on line 2, and "Instructor: " on line 3.

```
fu! CreateNote(subject, title)
   exe "e! " . fnameescape($NOTES_DIR . "/MS" . g:year . "/" . a:subject
   . "/" . a:title . ".txt")
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function could become something like that:

```
function! CreateNote(subject, title)
    exe "e! " . fnameescape($NOTES_DIR . "/MS" . g:year . "/" . a:subject . "/" . a:title . ".txt")

   let l:filename=bufname("%")
   let l:timestap=strftime("%c")
   let l:text="Instructor: "

   put! =l:filename
   put! =l:timestap
   put! =l:text

endfunction
```

The fist line is yours. It then creates 3 variables:

- The first one use `bufname("%")` to get the name of the current buffer ([`:h bufname()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#bufname())).
- The second one use the function `strftime` to get the current time. Beware it is a direct call to the C function so it might not be portable, see the doc for more details [`:h strftime()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#strftime()) (You can of course change the format of the timestamp cf. doc)
- The 3rd one simply contains some text.

Then the 3 last lines uses the function `put` ([`:h put`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:put)):

- The `!` is used to insert before the current line (otherwise as you start on the first line and `put` insert after the current line, you'd get an empty first line).
- The `=` is used to call the expression register allowing to get the content of the variables.

**Bonus** You can make the function sexier by using a list and iterating through it:

```
function! CreateNote(subject, title)
    exe "e! " . fnameescape($NOTES_DIR . "/MS" . g:year . "/" . a:subject . "/" . a:title . ".txt")

    let l:header=[ bufname("%"), strftime("%c"), "Instructor: " ]

    for l:line in l:header
        put! =l:line
    endfor
endfunction
```

Comment: Also you might be interested in the [dedicated Vim site](http://vi.stackexchange.com/) for your future questions about Vim :-)